# setBackground does not works on First time but on Second, Why?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, setbackground

I have seen this examlpe in a book , and is working fine but the only problem coming up is that the Background Does not turns black on First Call to Paint, When clearCounter become == 5, and then the screen is Cleared and again when Painting Starts, then the Background is turned Black.

```
public class apletprg extends JApplet implements ActionListener 
    {
int clearCounter;
    Timer t;
public void init(){

    setBackground(Color.black);
    clearCounter = 0;
    Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
    t.start();

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    setBackground(Color.black);
    clearCounter++;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if (clearCounter == 5){
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 400);
        clearCounter=0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        Color c = chooseColor();
        g2.setColor(c);
        Font f = chooseFont();
        g2.setFont(f);
        drawJava(g2);
        }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
repaint();
}
public Color chooseColor(){
int r= (int) (Math.random() * 255);
int g= (int) (Math.random() * 255);
int b= (int) (Math.random() * 255);
Color c = new Color(r,g,b);
return c;
}
public Font chooseFont(){

    int fontChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    Font f = null;
    switch (fontChoice) {
    case 1: f = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 20);break;
    case 2: f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 17);break;
    case 3: f = new Font("Monospaced", Font.ITALIC, 23);break;
    case 4: f = new Font("Dialog", Font.ITALIC, 30);break;
    }
    return f;

}
public void drawJava(Graphics2D g2){
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * 400);
    g2.drawString("Adnan", x, y);   
}
}
```

I Know that the Init () is called only once at the Start , but Why is that not able to change the Background at start?

Comment: I increased the `Timer` to 5000 msec to allow more time to see rendering artifacts and ran it a few times in the 1.7.0_25 applet viewer.  The BG turned black immediately every time.  Do you see words on top of the non-black BG?  What Java version is it running on?  Display or print the `System.getProperty("java.version")` from within the applet to make sure it is running in the version you expect.

Comment: Mine is 1.7.0_07, How can I Update that to use the Latest Version ?

Comment: I entered 'java latest version' into my favorite search engine, and the link was right at the top of listing.  You might give that a go.  ;)  And yes, definitely update it.  AFAIR those early versions of Java 7 were riddled with bugs.  Even worse, they have **publicly known** security exploits.  I would not feel safe surfing the net with such a Java version installed.

Comment: I have Latest version Installed as my Update Status Shows that java is update today, But Still Showing 1.7.0_07

Comment: Open the [Java Cache Viewer](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp).  Now close the viewer itself to see the Java Control Panel behind it.  Go to the Java tab of the JCP and click the View button.   You should see a table with column headers Platform | Product | Location | Path | Runtime Parameters | **Enabled** - make sure that 1.7.0_07  is *not* ticked.  Then shut down & restart your browser and try the applet again.

Comment: Cheched That , the Only Listed is 1.7.0_45, and that is Checked

Comment: If you are using an IDE probably you need to change the runtime there. Did you try calling repaint inside init?

Comment: *"Only Listed is 1.7.0_45"*  Huh..  There are two tabs above the table.  The default is User (where I *expected* you to see 1.7.0_07), but check the System tab for other versions as well..

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan  Thanks for transferring that comment.  :)  The OP reported it did not change anything, but at least others can know it has been suggested and tried.

Comment: ok Friends, Yes that was an Issue with the IDE, Now it is using the 1.7.0_45 update , but the Problem is Same , even changed timer to 5000, Background only changes after 5 Timer Calls :(

Comment: The Issue is that , When the First Time Applet is Loaded, i don't know but From Some Where the Background is set to White, And on the Fifth Timer Call , When ClearRect () clears that White Color to Display the ORIGINAL Background of the Applete, then the Black one got appeared, So How how to Get Rid Of that First White Background Color?

Comment: Import java.applet.Applet and make your class extend Applet instead of JApplet. Your code will work fine.

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan See my updated answer. This will work.

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan `Import java.applet.Applet and make your class extend Applet instead of JApplet.`  Noooooooo!  `JApplet` is the Swing equivalent of `Applet`, and works (or fails) just as well - ever since Swing was introduced.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added an answer if OP wants to use JApplet. I tested it on my system. super.paint() was not called after setting content pane's background.

Comment: *"ok Friends, Yes that was an Issue with the IDE"*  Note that you should 'finalize' this question and start a new one on the different topic.  I will collect my advice together into an answer on the original question..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't think Java version had anything to do here.

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan OK.  I'll let it go.  I was about to suggest you post the *"If you are using an IDE probably you need to change the runtime there."* as an answer to the *real* question, as it seems to me that the BG failed to paint in 1.7.0_07 & **did** paint in 1.7.0_25.  But I see the OP has moved on since then (and effectively *changed* the question - which is not an optimal thing to do!).  OTOH - let's run with it..  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think what OP meant by that comment was that `System.getProperty("java.version")` was returning his old version and that IDE was culprit. Anyway seems like he left disappointed. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the ProbleBy Just Adding One more Variable and Calling the ClearRect() at the Start of painting and to ensure that This will be Called only once , by the Help of Newly Added Variable.

public void init(){

```
    setBackground(Color.black);
    clearCounter = 0;

    Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
    t.start();
    check = 0;   <------------ New Variable


}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if (check==0){
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 400);   <------------ To Ensure That it will Excute Only Once , beacuse check is incremented later in Code
    }



    clearCounter++;
    check++;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if (clearCounter == 5){
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 400);
        clearCounter=0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        Color c = chooseColor();
        g2.setColor(c);
        Font f = chooseFont();
        g2.setFont(f);
        drawJava(g2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your init method replace `setBackground(Color.black)` with `getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black)`

And add `super.paint(g)` as the first line in your `paint` method.

Otherwise if you don't want to use Swing features then go ahead and import `java.applet.Applet` and make you class extend `Applet` instead of `JApplet`

```
public class NewClass extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    int clearCounter;
    Timer t;



    public void init() {

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        repaint();
        clearCounter = 0;
        //t = new Timer("1000", true);


    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        clearCounter++;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        if (clearCounter == 5) {
            g2.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 400);
            clearCounter = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
            Color c = chooseColor();
            g2.setColor(c);
            Font f = chooseFont();
            g2.setFont(f);
            drawJava(g2);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        repaint();
    }

    public Color chooseColor() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int g = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color c = new Color(r, g, b);
        return c;
    }

    public Font chooseFont() {

        int fontChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        Font f = null;
        switch (fontChoice) {
        case 1:
            f = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 20);
            break;
        case 2:
            f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 17);
            break;
        case 3:
            f = new Font("Monospaced", Font.ITALIC, 23);
            break;
        case 4:
            f = new Font("Dialog", Font.ITALIC, 30);
            break;
        }
        return f;

    }

    public void drawJava(Graphics2D g2) {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 400);
        g2.drawString("Adnan", x, y);
    }
}
```

If you want to execute super.paint() only once add a boolean variable in your class

```
boolean firstTime = true;
```

In paint()

```
if(firstTime) {
    super.paint(g);
    firstTime = false;
}
```

Comment: Your efforts were not entirely wasted.  +1  :)

Comment: Offcourse you are right in your opinion , But in paint(), the super.paint(g) removes the previous painted words every time it is repainted , but what i actually want to do is to remove the previous words only at every 5th call of repaint();

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan You can add that condition while calling `super.paint(g)`.

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan Look at the updated answer. The last part. I have tried it and it works.

Comment: Ya that worked too, and i got the result as Below too